# Android BroadcastReceiver not firing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This code used to work fine on older android versions.  When I updated it with latest Android Studio it no longer works.

I am trying to send a simple string from one of my classes to the main activity.

I declare the receiver in my manifest...

```
<receiver android:name="com.domain.appname.MainActivity$MyReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="MY_ACTION"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When trying to send the broadcast using an intent.  This is when the location is detected as changed

```
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        addStats("onLocationChanged - "+mLastLocation.getLatitude()+" "+mLastLocation.getLongitude()+" "+mLastLocation.getAccuracy()+" "+mLastLocation.getSpeed());
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        //send latitude, longitude and accuracy as broadcast to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("DATAPASSED", mLastLocation.getLatitude()+" "+mLastLocation.getLongitude()+" "+mLastLocation.getAccuracy()+" "+mLastLocation.getSpeed());
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        addStats("after sendBroadcast");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
}
```

The addStats lines in there are just for debugging and they all fire.  ie I see the stats for it detecting new long/lat and I get the "after sendBroadcast" message, so it looks like that code is sending (or attempting to send) the broadcast.

Now in my main activity I have this as the receiver...

```
//receives the broadcasts from the MyLocationService service
public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        addStats("inside onReceive");
        String datapassed = arg1.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED");
    }
}
```

That never gets triggered.  I never see the "inside onReceive" message.

Any ideas what I may be missing?  Been through a lot of stackoverflow and google results and the above seems to be what I need to get this working.  As I said it used to work fine (maybe version 26 of Android), but I am trying to get this app running on newer OS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use an explicit intent. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197540/383676.

However, if you're broadcasting within the same app a better option would be to use:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Many thanks.  The LocalBroadcastManager did the trick.  I used the same code as in this message.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/4237309